# Why shouldn't this prove the prime number theorem?

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

Someone deduced without using complex analysis that

$$ \int \frac{\pi(t)}{t^2} \mathrm{d}t \sim \log\log t $$
where $\pi$ is the prime counting function.

By differentiating the above, he then arrives at

$$\frac{\pi(t)}{t^2} \sim \frac{1}{t\log t} $$ which is exactly the Prime Number Theorem.

However, he feels that something should be wrong with this approach, but not sure exactly what ?

Comment: Where did you bring the first relation from?

Comment: @ArashMohammadi It follows e.g. from one of Mertens' estimates for $\sum1/p$ and Abel's summation formula.

Comment: Supplemental to the answers below: If $f(t) \sim g(t)$ as $t\to \infty$ then $f(t)=g(t)(1+h(t))$ where $h(t)\to 0$ as $t\to \infty.$ So $f'(t)/g'(t)=1+h(t)+g(t)h'(t)/g'(t).$  Without more info about $h(t)$ we can't even estimate $h'(t),$ let alone estimate $f'(t)/g'(t).$

Answer (score 34):

The reasoning is flawed because $f\sim g$ most certainly does NOT imply $f’\sim g’$.

For example, take $f(x)\equiv 0$ and $g(x)= \frac1N \sin N^2x$.

Comment: @barto it means $f/g\to 1$.

Comment: To avoid the zeroes-problem, I'd suggest to take something like $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x+\sin x^2$

Comment: What does $f(x)\equiv 0$ mean?

Comment: @EricDuminil It means $f$ is the zero function, i.e. $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Thanks. But why use a different notation for $f$ and $g$?

Comment: @EricDuminil the expression for $g(x)$ involves $x$, so there is no ambiguity that $g(x) = \frac{1}{N} \sin N^2 x$ is a definition (as by convention of equality symbol). On the contrary, $f(x) = 0$ may be confused as an equation, rather than a definition, so sometimes people use $\equiv$ to emphasize they do mean $f(x)$ **equals** the constant function 0.

Comment: @EricDuminil : Meaning that $f$ is identically zero, not uncommon notation

Comment: It is not an uncommon notation, but it is rooted on the (very common) bad habit of using "f(x)" to denote a function named $f$. In the case above, $f=0$ would have been perfectly clear.

Comment: @MartinArgerami : Not the case here. I'm simply specifying the rule of assignment. The comment of user31415 is essentially on the mark. This lets the notation I use for $f$ and $g$ remain parallel.

Answer (score 23):

$f\sim g$ does not imply $f'\sim g'$! L'hopital's rule only works in one direction:
$$\log x \sim \log \left((5+\sin x)x\right) \quad\text{but}\quad\frac1{x}\nsim\frac{((5+\sin x)x)'}{(5+\sin x)x}$$
or if you want,
$$\log\log x \sim \log \log \left((5+\sin x)x\right) \quad\text{but}\quad\frac1{x\log x}\nsim\frac{((5+\sin x)x)'}{(5+\sin x)x \cdot \log\left((5+\sin x)x\right)}$$
(The factor $5+\sin x$ is there just to make the second quotient misbehave.)

The point is that we don't know (a priori) that
$$\frac{\pi(x)}{x/\log x}$$
has a limit for $x\to\infty$.

---

What l'Hopital does tell us, is that *if* the limit of $(\pi(x)\log x)/x$ exists, then it is $1$.

I believe Chebyshev's original proof (and any subsequent ones) of this fact also goes along these lines, via a Mertens-type estimate for $\sum_{p\leq x}1/p\sim\int_1^x\pi(t)/t^2$.

Comment: Good addition that it does give a valid proof that _if_ the limit from the Prime Number Theorem exists, then it is equal to $1$. The biography page [http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Chebyshev.html](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Chebyshev.html) confirms that Chebyshev (Чебышёв) had proved this (around 1850 when his results were strong enough to prove Bertrand's postulate). That the limit actually exists was not proved until 1896, two years after his death.